# GnuCash expense report by account with multiple currencies

Tags: gnucash

I'm trying to report the total value of my business expenses over a tax period.

My expenses are recorded under `Expenses` in ZAR (primary currency) and some hosting expenses are recorded in USD. When I run an Expense Report, my USD expenses are not included in the report.

How can I run a report that includes the total debit/credit value of all my accounts over a period in one currency, or in multiple currencies?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a technical issue.

Comment: How is a technical issue off-topic?